# How to create one color whit the grayscale of another?

Tags: image-processing, colors

In Unity I can get the grayscale of a color by using `Color.grayscale`.

But How can I give the grayscale taken by a given **color "A"** into a given **color "B"**?
In other terms, How can I create Colors with different tints, but same grayscales?

Comment: Do you mean you want to find other (R,G,B) colors that happen to convert to the same grayscale / intensity?  The rgb => gs formula is here : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color-grayscale.html  so it's an algebra problem to find other r, g, b such that gs(r,g,b) = X

Comment: I removed the tags for `C#` and `Unity` since there is no code problem. You are asking about a graphics process here, it's not anything to do with a `C#` compiler.